# How to deploy django with nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, linux, nginx, uwsgi

i have a problem to deploy my django server with uwsgi and nginx.

The command `dev_ralph runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` starts the development server and works fine.
But my goal now is to deploy a production django server and as i said, i have some problems with that.

My project-root-directory is: `/home/ralphadmin/uwsgi/capentory-ralph/ralph`

Here is the nginx-virtualhost-configuration:
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/ralph.conf` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ralph.conf`:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///home/ralphadmin/uwgsi/capentory-ralph/ralph/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 10.70.7.1; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        root /home/ralphadmin/uwsgi/capentory-ralph/ralph/src/ralph/static/; # your Django project's static files
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ralphadmin/uwsgi/capentory-ralph/ralph/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you ins$
    }
}
```

As you can see, my static-files are located in `/home/ralphadmin/uwsgi/capentory-ralph/ralph/src/ralph/static/`

And if i try to connect with the server, that default nginx page is in my browser:
[nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kao6P.png)

I would really appreciate some helpful comments.

----------- Update 1

I investigated my nginx-logs and found this:

```
2020/02/11 15:18:44 [error] 19097#19097: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 10.70.7.254, server: 10.70.7.1, request: "GET / 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://10.70.7.1:8630", host: "10.70.7.1"

2020/02/11 15:31:55 [error] 19492#19492: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 10.70.7.254, server: 10.70.7.1, request: "GET 
/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://10.70.7.1:8630", host: "10.70.7.1", 
referrer: "http://10.70.7.1/"
```

... uwsgi is running but still, it doesn't work at all :(

Comment: 5** statuses mean server side failure. Investigate the logs.

Comment: What you see is not the default nginx page but an error page. You should take a look at the logs in `/var/logs/nginx` to determine the cause of the error. Probably it cannot connect to uwsgi (did you start uwsgi?).

Comment: I didn't try uwsgi, but I recommend using Gunicorn instead of uwsgi.